# How do I create a react-native full-screen modal that will cover a SafeAreaView with tabs?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

If I have a bottom tab navigator and I the screens within that navigator to navigate to a modal which will be truly full-screen (covering `SafeAreaView`), how do i I do that? From what i understand, `AppContainer` has to be rendered within `SafeAreaView`, if I'm using `SafeAreaView`.  So that makes it tricky to use a modal outside of `SafeAreaView`.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home,
    ScreenA,
    ScreenB,
    ScreenC,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      safeAreaInset: { bottom: 'never' },
    },
  }
);

const TabsAndModal = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs,
    Modal,
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabsAndModal);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
      <AppContainer />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

This causes the modal to slide up from the bottom, but it starts at the `SafeAreaView` on an iphone X, so the blue background is visible just below.  What is the right way to do this, so that the modal slides up from the very bottom of an an iphone x and the tabs are still rendered within `SafeAreaView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked something fairly straightforward in `createBottomTabNavigator`:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'readTheDocsOfReactNavigationTabs',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppContainer should not be rendered inside `SafeAreaView`. Read about how to handle it in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html